# An action hook where a comment meta is updated

Tags: comments, hooks, actions, sql, comment-meta

By analogy to the hook on  post meta update, I use the following code for hooking when comment meta value is updated.

My comment meta key is "consider" and can have 2 values: 0 and 1.

My Goal is to count number of comments with `consider=1`, and when this count reaches 10, perform some operations.

```
            add_action( 'update_comment_meta', 'ten_considered_comments_badge');

            function ten_considered_comments_badge($meta_id, $comment_id, $key, $value)
                {
                    if ( 'consider' != $key or 1!= $value)  return;

                    $com=get_comment($comment_id);
                    if ( !$com  )  return;

               $args = array(
  'type' => '',
  'user_id' => $com->user_id,
  'meta_key' => 'consider',
  'meta_value' => '1',
);
$com2= get_comments($args);
             $count = count($com2);

                     if( $count%10==0) {

     $number_of_bronze_badges= get_user_meta($com->user_id,'user_number_of_bronze_badges',true);
        $number_of_bronze_badges= $number_of_bronze_badges + 1;

        update_user_meta($com->user_id, 'user_number_of_bronze_badges', $number_of_bronze_badges);
        }
        }
```

What I am missing in this code . Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You are obviously missing the part that would actually "perform some operations" but other than that, what isn't working? Also, `0%10 === 0` so this will probably execute when you don't want it to.

Comment: Thank you @s_ha_dum. I edited adding the operations, for the sake of simplicity I didnt add them. and about `if( $count%10==0)` , it is because i want the operations be done when $count is equal to 10, 20, 30...At first, is the logic behind  the hook correct?

Comment: Yes, but what you have will execute when `$count` equals 0 as well as 10,20,30 and so on.

Comment: I agree with you, but when I execute the sql query in phpmyadmin it gives me a count different than zero, and it is incremented correcly when a comment meta is changed from 0 to 1

Comment: Okey-dokey. It is your (potential) bug, not mine. You didn't answer my question, "What isn't working?" It is hard to tell you what is missing if I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: just excuse the fact I forgot editing, and also excuse if I dont understand you well. I am a beginner from non-english country.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9463/discussion-between-s-ha-dum-and-whiteletters-and-blankspaces)

Answer (score 1):

I think you only want `get_comment` and not `get_comments` on this line:

```
$com=get_comments($comment_id);
```

You are only checking for a single comment, by the ID. `get_comments` won't do that the way you are using it.

There is a check [halfway through the `update_metadata` function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L127) that compares the existing value to new value under some circumstances. That runs before the `update_comment_meta` hook and sometimes `return`s so that that hook never runs. Admittedly this is a guess, but if you are passing the same value, such as `true` every time this may be where it hangs.

The `update_{$meta_type}_metadata` hook would fire, but is a filter and not really the best choice for this kind of hook. I am wondering if you shouldn't be using the [`edit_comment` hook instead](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/comment.php#L1526).

Comment: I am really sorry for not giving edit about your first remark, I changed get_comments by get_comment, and also I changed the SQL with the code you provided me in one of your answers. Give me one minute and I will provide with the whole new code.

Comment: I edited and I am now trying to understand the other remarks and ideas you provided, really big thanks for the help you are always giving me and giving to the whole wordpress developpers.

Comment: Go back to chat please. Use the link in the last comment under the question