# Does update_comment_meta hook exists?

Tags: hooks, actions

Its been 3 days now I am fighting to resolve the issue here:

[An action hook where a comment meta is updated](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104817/an-action-hook-where-a-comment-meta-is-updated)

I am pretty sure, even if I am a beginner, that the  hook `update_comment_meta` doesnt exist, and that it is not possible to use something like:

```
add_action( 'update_comment_meta', 'do_soemthing', 10, 4);
```

Any confirmations, or objections are highly welcomed.

Comment: How is this question different from the one you asked earlier and linking to?

Comment: Thank you Rarst for your time. In fact, after too much time looking for the solution to my linked question, I start even believing that there is no hook with the name `update_comment_meta`. I came back here to get confirmation that there is a hook with such name, because really no ressources on internet about this (also I am newbie).

Comment: @Rarst, I use `update_post_meta` with no problems, and when I use the same way `update_comment_meta`, it doesnt work, all code in my callback is executing outside, but never inside callback. I come here for expert ideas, really no discussion about this hook on internet .

Comment: Please elaborate on how you are using the hook in core. From the answer you got it does exist and should work.

Comment: I think the linked topic explains how I am using the hook. I will give more explanations as an edit. Also I will accept the answer above since you also confirm it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's a little bit complicated ;)

If you will search `update_comment_meta` hook, you won't find it.

But it exists :)

There is `update_comment_meta` function and it calls `update_metadata` function with first param set to `comment`.

This `update_metadata` function does something like this (meta.php line 149):

```
do_action( "update_{$meta_type}_meta", $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value );
```

where `$meta_type` is the first param of this function.

So it will be `update_comment_meta` when this function is called by `update_comment_meta` function (because `$meta_type` is then equal to `'comment'`).

Comment: thank you for your answer, I am totally agreeing with the logic behind your answer, and this is the logic I followed, but unfortunately the calleback function never executes. Did you checked my linked post? Thanks

Comment: Well, I did not. I'll check it later today.